# Mantaflow problem: I can't get any particles to bake in a closed shape anymore

Tags: mantaflow

I'm working on an animation using mantaflow and I'm having problems trying to increase the amount of liquid that my liquid domain emits. I tried scaling up the volume of the emitting geometry but it just got messy and then I tried starting from scratch but nothing is working. I also tried flipping the normals of the effector's geometry and removing all modifiers. I even started the animation from the beginning again, and I followed the exact steps I took the first time it worked but it's either not emitting particles or filling the whole domain with liquid. I need some help desperately!! I'm going crazy over this...

the first image is what I get now and the second is what I was doing a few days ago... don't know where I went wrong...

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a bit difficult to know what's wrong from your limited description, but one problem with Blender is that Domains that based on a Cache that is "Replay" often doesn't clear the cache when you've made changes.  Try setting the Type to "Modular" and check the box for Is Resumable.

Comment: hello James!! thank you very much for your reply, I'm sorry my description is limited, I don't know much about technical terms so it's a bit hard for me to explain... I've already selected modular resumable cache type for every bake I was doing before, but it still didn't work. I think I might try with version 2.8 (I read somewhere it might be a bug of the newer versions) or opening up the collision object mesh. what do you think about these solutions? thank you very much!!

Comment: I have not found much difference between fluid simulations in 2.8 and 2.9.  Have you completely deleted the cache folder of the fluid?  Not sure about your "opening up the collision object mesh".   You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ if you want to share your blend file; you can remove any objects not involved in the problem if you have "proprietary" work.

Comment: Hello James!! Thank you very much for all of your help. I was finally able to fix it yesterday by opening a small hole in the mesh of the containing object. I think I must have been a problem with the normals after all. I did remove all the cache of the fluid too, so maybe it was that. Thank you!!